# SSRS in .net Core 2.0, How can i make this happen?

Tags: c#, rest, soap, asp.net-core-2.0

I Need to be able to access reports on SSRS, in order to view and list them using .Net Core 2.0. I need to be able to display a list of reports from the server in a dropdown list. Should I use SOAP API, or is that even possible in .Net core 2.0?

This is new territory for me as this is the first exposure to SSRS. I have been reading the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/accessing-the-soap-api?view=sql-server-2017

I am currently pulling back the reports using this:[https://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/](https://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks%202008R2/) which is terrible , however it works.

I need to be able to access the SSRS reports in the .Net Core 2.0 application. If anyone can link me something more useful to read I would greatly appreciate it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this: [MVC .NET Core Report Viewer](https://alanjuden.com/2016/11/10/mvc-net-core-report-viewer/)

Comment: Thanks, I will look over this and appreciate the information.